# Do I need to download jQuery if I have the jquery-rails gem?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use jCrop in my application, which is reliant on jQuery. It says I have to download jQuery, but if I already have it installed as a gem, is that sufficient? I downloaded jQuery UI and am using it's autocomplete widget just fine, so doesn't that mean I already have basic jQuery?

I'm just paranoid about messing around with my development environment; I don't want to download something unnecessary and mess everything up somehow.

Here's what I have in my gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'
```

Comment: You can just look at the page source in your browser to see if you have jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not modified the application.js file (located inside app/assets/javascripts/), you will see that at the bottom of it the jquery is included in this file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
```

So if your application.js file has `//= require jquery`, rails will render it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try `bundle install gem` in command line.. to make sure all of the gems in your gemfile are loading up properly.

If that doesn't work go into your index.html file and and put this above your header:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This brings in jquery without having to download the files to your computer.

Best of luck!